Determinant upper bound for specific matrix form
Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be a symmetric matrix with the following properties:

$A_{ij} \leq 0 \text{ for } i \neq j$
$A_{ii} \geq 0 \ \forall i \in [d]$
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^d A_{ij} = 0 \ \forall j \in [d]$

(from the symmetry of $A$, the third property holds for columns as well).
Let $B$ be the diagonal approximation of $A$, namely $B = A \circ I$.
Since $A$ is positive semi-definite (see here), we have $\det(A + I) \leq \det(B + I)$ from Hadamard's inequality.
Now, Let $C \in \mathbb{R}_+^{d \times q}$ for $q \leq d$. i.e, $C$ has nonnegative entries.
How can I prove that $\det(C^TAC + I) \leq \det(C^TBC + I)$?

It is probably best to write $B = I \circ A$.  What's the source of this inequality?  The fact that the desired inequality is impossible if you remove your $C$ has non-negative entries requirement should be kind of obvious since $A$ will always have an eigenvalue strictly bigger than $B$ outside of special cases like $A=\mathbf 0$.

Good point. I edited the question to reflect that. This inequality arises from an optimization problem I'm trying to solve where the upper bound is more well behaving than the original objective (LHS). $C$ can be thought of as a more general data sample embeddings than the one-hot encoding "degenerate" case (corresponding to $C=I$)
